# Order of construction of nested objects and member variables

Tags: scala

I create this object in REPL. And then tested its setup sequence in the attached image below. The results are confusing.

```
object T {
  val default = A
  var options = List[P]()
  println(options)

  sealed trait P

  object A extends P {
    override def toString = "A"
    println(T.options)
    println("A")
  }

  object B extends P {
    override def toString = "B"
    println(T.options)
    println("A")
  }

  object C extends P {
    override def toString = "C"
    println(T.options)
    println("A")
  }
}
```

1. In the first run, T, only the inner object A seems to be constructed. Why dont the object B and object C print anything??
2. Also note that println(T.options) in the first run returns "null". Is this because first inner objects are setup and then the outer objects other members are setup?
3. On typing T.A nothing is printed because the object is already setup.
4. On typing T.B it setsup the B object and prints the T.options correctly i.e List() instead of null.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the first run, `T`, only the inner object `A` seems to be constructed.
>   Why dont the object `B` and object `C` print anything??

Because they aren't *initialized*, they're only *declared*. The reason `A` prints out is because of:

```
val default = A
```

Which causes `A` to initialize. The order of initialization is thus:

1. `T`s `default` variable causes `A` to initalize
2. `A` initializes and prints `null`
3. `T` now continues initialization and now sets a value to `options`

Any further invocation will now print the content of the list instead of `null`.

> Also note that `println(T.options)` in the first run returns "null". Is
>   this because first inner objects are setup and then the outer objects
>   other members are setup?

That's because `println(T.options)` happens in `A`s constructor, which is prior to your `options` initialization inside `T`s constructor.

> On typing `T.A` nothing is printed because the object is already setup.

That makes perfect sense, `A` doesn't anything additional that needs to be initialized.

> On typing `T.B` it sets up the `B` object and prints the `T.options`
>   correctly i.e `List()` instead of `null`.

That's right, because once you invoke `T.B`, you've already initialized the list via `T`s constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The `val default = A` was the devil here. :(

Comment: @Samar You welcome. Yes, that's what was causing the cascade of invocations.